# How to apply sticky headers for multiple rows(both th and tr) in thead?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am trying to get a sticky header(which is having multiple tr and th) for my data table in angular material.

Here is my below css for head to apply sticky

**scss**

```
thead {
      tr.mat-header-row {
        position: sticky;
        position: -webkit-sticky !important;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: inherit !important;
      }
        border: 1px solid rgb(250,250,250);
        background-color: #CCCCCC;
      }
    }
```

**HTML** file

```
<thead>
    <tr class="mat-header-row" *ngFor="let headerRow of headerData">
      <th *ngFor="let head of headerRow" [attr.rowspan]="head.rowspan" [attr.colspan]="head.colspan" class="mat-header-cell tree-table-header" [matTooltip]="head.name" matTooltipPosition="above">
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead >

<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
    <mat-tree-node class="mat-row" *matTreeNodeDef="let mynode">...
    </mat-tree-node>
  <mat-tree>
```

Content should be scrollable and header should be sticky this is what the exact scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far I can see they have an input on the row that allows you to do that. *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true". open https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview and search for Sticky Rows and Columns

Comment: You need to implement the [Angular Material Table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) properly with correct syntax and then add sticky to row as @m.popov said.

Comment: @m.popov yes , But facing the below error
ERROR in : Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute prefixed with * ("
>
because I am also using *ngFor in tr

Comment: Also this `let headerData of headerData` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Vishnudev I just mocked the variables ..Thanks for spotted this mistake.